# Submit Button in the smart Capture Form not working - not redirecting to Submit Page

Tags: marketing-cloud

I  have smart capture form  in the landing page and I have written code to pre populate the fields in the smart capture form

1. Passed parameter in the URL
2. In the smart capture form inside the filed used QueryParameter and set the value , added the below code

   `<script> %%[
        var @FName,@LName,@EmailAdd,@Login
        SET @FName =""
        SET @LName =""
        SET @EmailAdd =""
        SET @Login  =""
        SET @Login = QUERYPARAMETER('LoginID')
        SET @FName = Lookup('IPD Remediation List', 'FirstName1', 'LoginID', @Login)
     ]%%
   </script>`
3. This pre populates  the value but when I add this code the Submit button does not work.

If I remove this code the Submit works and the DE gets populated.

Can some one  point the issue here?

Thanks and Regards,
Anumol Antony

Comment: have you tried adding this as a new content area, at the top of the CloudPage? you don't need the <script> </script>  tag. and no need to set Fname and Login twice in the script.

Comment: As @CodeRage said, it is likely that you are opening with `<script>` and closing with `</script>` which is nullifying the shorthand script declaration of `%%[ ]%%` meaning that your AMPscript is not run and likely is causing a syntax error.